# How do you use multiple dotnet core unit test target frameworks in Travis-CI?

Tags: .net-core, travis-ci

I am developing an api targeting .NetStandard, and want to test it with different versions of .NetCore.

I would like to run my unit tests against all the currently supported LTS versions of .NetCore, however I cannot figure out how to build the unit tests against the currently installed SDK.

The currently supported versions of .NetCore are 2.1 and 3.1. I can use `<TargetFrameworks>` to specify that the unit test project can handle both those targets, and when I run on my dev machine everything works fine. However, unlike my dev machine, when Travis runs tests there is only one SDK installed (which is good - I want to know exactly what I'm testing against). The unit test project expects both SDKs to present, however. If I target only 2.1 it fails for 3.1 on Travis, and if I target 3.1 it fails for 2.1.

So, is there a way to test against both LTS versions of .NetCore on Travis-CI with a single unit test project?

Comment: What you should do is to follow the practices of others, such as Noda Time, https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/3.0.0-beta01/.travis.yml

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get it working.

1. In the unit test project use `TargetFrameworks` instead of `TargetFramework` to target multiple frameworks. I believe you have to edit the csproj file by hand, I don't think there's a way to set it from the Visual Studio UI.  `<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.1;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>`
2. In .travis.yml, include one framework in the `dotnet:` section, explicitly install the other framework in the `before_install:` section, then explicitly invoke the tests with each framework in the `script:` section:

```
dotnet: # Include one of the frameworks
  - 2.1.804 # EOL for 2.1: 2021.08.21
before_install:
  # explicitly install other targeted SDKs side by side
  - sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.1
script:
  # explicitly identify the framework when invoking the tests
  - dotnet test UnitTests/UnitTests.csproj -f netcoreapp2.1
  - dotnet test UnitTests/UnitTests.csproj -f netcoreapp3.1
```